# Noun clauses types

Tags: grammar, noun-clause

I have trying to figure out what the following means and I still can't get my head around it. They talk about "bound" independent clause but my mind keeps saying: "you mean dependent clause"

Can someone explain to me the concept they are trying to teach?

- **Bold** is the flag word
- *Italic* is the whole noun clause (including the bold part)

> (***That***) type noun clauses are built like adverb clauses in that the flag
> word is put in front of a “bound” independent clause, and the flag
> word plays no grammatical role inside the “bound” independent clause:
>
> that type noun clause = that type flag word + “bound” independent
> clause
>
> Example: ***Whether or not** it rains* will determine our destination
>
> (***Wh-***) type noun clauses are built like adjective clauses in
> that wh- words (like relative pronouns in adjective clauses) are
> inside the “bound” independent clause. Thus, the wh- word must play
> some grammatical role within the “bound” independent clause. Let us
> look again at the four example sentences, this time focusing on the
> grammatical role of the flag word:
>
> Example: ***Whatever you decide*** is fine with us.

***Source**: English grammar and usage (Lester & Beason) p56,57,63. [Link](https://schoolbag.info/language/grammar_3/4.html).*

Comment: Briefly, "whatever you decide" is best analysed not as a clause but as a noun **phrase** in a 'fused' relative construction, where the meaning is "anything you decide".

Comment: So what do they mean by this: “bound” independent clause?

Comment: Their idea is that a bound relative clause has an explicit external antecedent, as in "I've eaten the **food** [that you gave me]" while a free relative does not. Instead, it is not explicit but is contained within the relative clause, as in "I've eaten [**what** you gave me]". Integrated and 'fused' are much clearer terms. Note that your first example is not a relative construction at all, but one that contains a subordinate interrogative clause.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] [*Whatever you decide*] *is fine with us.*
>
> [2] [*Whether or not it rains*] *will determine our destination.*

This explanation may be clearer.

In [1] the subject "whatever you decide" is best analysed not as a clause but as a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction. The meaning is like that of the non-fused "anything you decide".

In [2] "whether or not it rains" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as subject. It identifies a question the answer to which will determine our destination.

Comment: For clarity, a "fused" relative clause means one that is not bound to an antecedent, but acts as a complete phrase, as these noun phrases do.

Comment: @gotube No: the term 'fused relative clause' is misleading. "Whatever you decide" is not a clause but a noun phrase, as I made clear in my answer. [2] is quite different: "whether or not it rains" is not a noun phrase in a fused relative construction but a subordinate interrogative clause, again as I made clear in my answer.

Comment: @BillJ Can you expand on this: "a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction" 
Can you give me a couple of examples so I can understand.

Comment: How can I identify what is fused and what is not fused